Azure B2C Authorization consent screen
I'm following this guide (https://medium.com/@shoaib.alam/part-2b-oauth-2-0-authorization-code-grant-with-azure-ad-d97b213ecc9) to create an Azure Application and request access to it using Authorization Code Flow (OAUTH2).
In the example, Microsoft Login prompt the user (After the login) for access to the resource (in this case is called DemoClientApp01:

But in my case this screen is skipped. Just login and get the Authorization Code and then I can change it for the JWT Token.
What controls in Azure when this screen is shown? If I add a new custom Scope/Permission it does not show also.
Thanks very much.
Regards;
Fernando

Any update on the issue?

For sample, I created an Azure AD B2C application and added permissions like below:

And used the below endpoint to generate the auth code:
https://b2c.b2clogin.com/b2c.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SUSI/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://b2c.onmicrosoft.com/ClientID/test.read
&state=12345

And got the same issue as you, generated auth code without consent screen:


Note that: Azure AD B2C do not support consent screen that is the user consent screen for accepting the permissions requested. Refer this SO Thread by Jas Suri - MSFT.


You can make use of custom policy to create your own consent screen logic.

And so, you need to grant admin consent to the permissions added:



Now I tried the same in Microsoft Entra ID/Azure AD.

https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=User.Read
&state=12345

I got the consent screen successfully for Microsoft Entra ID application:

Reference:
Did not have user consent when expose web API in B2C tenant · Issue #329 · Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2 · GitHub by nickgmicrosoft
